# $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-|x|}$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to prove that $f:B\to \mathbb R^n$, $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-|x|}$, where $B\subset R^n$ is an open ball centered at origin and radius $1$ is not uniformly continuous.

I've already tried find some sequences such that this propriety fail:

$\lim (x_n-y_n)=0\implies \lim(f(x_n)-f(y_n))=0$

or find some uniformly continuous function such that its composition with $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Are there another techniques I can use to prove this function is not uniformly continuous?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: what happens when $x$ goes near +/- $1$?

Comment: $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Aram: Are you assuming $n=1$?

Comment: @Zircht but if $f$ is continuous, $f(B)$ should be bounded, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. The image of $f$ would be bounded if, for instance, its domain were compact.

Comment: @Zircht But there is a theorem which says $f:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous and $X\subset \mathbb R^m$ is bounded then $f(X)$ is bounded.

Comment: No. Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ defined on $(0,1)$. This function is continuous, its domain is bounded but $f(0,1) = (1,\infty)$, which is unbounded.

Comment: @Rob1.7: That is true but not relevant to your fucntion, because the domain is not $\mathbb R^m$.  The function you're asking about is continuous and unbounded.

Comment: @Rob1.7 your function is not continuous on all of $\mathbb R ^n$, so you can't use that theorem (it's not continuous on the sphere of radius 1)

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried to find sequences where $x_n-y_n\to 0$ but $f(x_n)-f(y_n)\not\to 0$.  How about these sequences?
$$x_n: .9, .99, .999, \dots$$ and $$y_n: .99, .999, .9999, \dots$$

Comment: It worked! thank you very much

Comment: I have a quick question regarding this map: what if it was $f(x) := \frac{1}{x-x_{o}}$ where $x_{o} \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of being restricted to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$? Would this map still not be uniformly continuous? @paw88789